# Add callback to observable before subscribing

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I'm facing some difficulties with Rxjs library and especially with Observables :

I have an angular 2 application that calls an API with HTTP library that returns Observable

The fact is that when i have a function to update a user :

```
function updateUser(user: User) {
    return this.http.put("http://myAPI/user/update, user)  
}
```

I'd like to update the user on each updateUser call without doing it on the calling side like :

```
function updateUser(user: User) {
    return this.http.put("http://myAPI/user/update", user).addCallback( updatedUser => {
        this.user = updatedUser.json()
    })
}
```

To be clear, i'd like to put a function that is called every time the "updateUser()" is subscribed.

Is there any way to do it ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: what do you mean by "update the user en oeach updateUser call without doing it on the calling side." ?

Comment: Sorry i've updated the post and gave and example of what i'me expecting for

Comment: Sorry, still don't quite understand what you are looking for. Do you want to update the user object that you pass in to the function? Or do you want to modify the function so it always returns the json after the update?

Comment: What i want is to add a function that will be called every time someone subscribes to the updateUser() function to update automatically the user from API response

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to manipulate the return value from your observable so you always return the user.

If that is the case you can use the Observable.map function

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-map

In your case it could look something like this

```
function updateUser(user: User) {
    return this.http.put("http://myAPI/user/update", user)
        .map(response => {
            return response.json();
        });
}
```

Comment: That's not what i'm expecting for : 
 In my class API i have the function "updateUser()" and the member "user: User".

In the class B i call "API.updateUser().subscribe()"

But i dont want to to "API.user = updatedUser.json()" in class B, i want to automatically do it in class API